# Event before save order or place order in magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer, sales-order, ce-1.9.1.1

Get event before place order or save new order. I have tried the `sales_order_save_before` event but I didn't get any data. Below is my code,
In `config.xml`:

```
<sales_order_save_before>
    <observers>
        <custom_observerwww>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Custom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>removeItems</method>
        </custom_observerwww>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_before>
```

In `Observer.php`:

```
class Custom_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function removeItems($observer){
        Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getOrder(),null,"order.log",true);
    }
```

There is no data received in log file.

Comment: In your mage::log if you replace `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` with any other text does that appear in your log?

Comment: yes.It gets printed

Comment: so then the event actually works, its just that the order might not be available

Comment: yes.I don't know how to get order data before save or place

Comment: are  you want to fire always whenever there are some chnage will be done. As per as magento system, whenever any change done at order then `sales_order_save_before`.

Comment: Just I want the event before place new order

Answer (score 11):

Try this da. It worked for me.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Always_Nallavan>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Always_Nallavan>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <alwaysnallavan>
                <class>Nallavan_Model</class>
            </alwaysnallavan>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <always_nallavan_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Always_Nallavan_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>dandanaka</method>
                    </always_nallavan_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Always_Nallavan_Model_Observer
{

    public function dandanaka($observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::log($data->debug(), null, "order.log", true);
    }
}
```

Note the `debug()` method, that returns a string representation of any `Varien_Object` instance.

Comment: @vinothavan what does dandanaka ah danakkunakka mean? lol :-)

Comment: @invissible Its just a method name man.

Comment: I understood but when I read that method name I understood that you are TR follower :-)

Comment: Ok invissible. Nandri :)

Comment: நன்றி நன்றி நன்றி

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know your event is working you should be able to get the order by the following:

`$observer->getOrder()`
or
`$observer->getEvent()->getData('order')`

Comment: Already I tried like this not working

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code it will definitely work.

**1st STEP**:

app/code/local/Demo/Observerexample/Model/Observer.php

```
class Demo_Observerexample_Model_Observer
{

    public function send_email($observer)
    {

        $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');

        foreach ($orderIds as $_orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
            $store = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            //$customer  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getData('customer_id'));
            //$customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
            $billingaddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $Ordercreated = $order->getCreatedAt();
            $OrderId = $order->getIncrementId();
            $Getstaus = $order->getStatusLabel();
            $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription(); // Shipping address for perticular product part.
            $country = $billingaddress->getCountry();
            $countryName = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country)->getName();

            try {
                $params = array('customerName' => $order->getData('customer_firstname'),
                    'customerlastname' => $order->getData('customer_lastname'),
                    'telephone' => $billingaddress->getData('telephone'),
                    'email' => $billingaddress->getData('email'),
                    'street' => $billingaddress->getData('street'),
                    'city' => $billingaddress->getData('city'),
                    'region' => $billingaddress->getData('region'),
                    'postcode' => $billingaddress->getData('postcode'),
                    'total' => $order->getGrandTotal());

                //var_dump($Getstaus);
                //die();

                /* $url= 'http://localhost/allcat/getorders.php';         // the url on which the data will be send through curl
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                $response = curl_exec($ch); 
                curl_close($ch);
                Mage::log('Order has been sent to exmaple.com'); */

                $dbhost = '';
                $dbuser = '';
                $dbpass = '';
                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                if (!$conn) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                if ($store) {

                    $short_code = 'web10';

                    $orderItemsCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
                    foreach ($orderItemsCollection as $item) {

                        $productName = $item->getName();
                        $productQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                        $productPrice = $item->getPrice();
                        $payment_method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO crm_order_management (email,product,comment,lname,qty,orderamt,pname,paymode,orderfro,despdate,orderid,status,storename,fname,short_code)
                                                   VALUES ('" . $params['email'] . "','" . $productName . "','" . $params['customerName'] . "','" . $params['customerlastname'] . "','" . $productQty . "','" . $params['total'] . "','" . $params['telephone'] . "','" . $payment_method . "','" . $params['city'] . "','" . $Ordercreated . "','" . $OrderId . "','" . $Getstaus . "','" . $store . "','" . $countryName . "','" . $short_code . "')";
                        mysql_select_db('abortion_word');
                        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

                        if (!$retval) {
                            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
                    }
                }

                mysql_close($conn);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because this code shows an Observer being a Model which is not needed, variables are named in weird ways (starting with capitals, with underscores), everything is combined in a single function (violating SOLID) and a database connection is created using deprecated `mysql` functions instead of using the DBO system of Magento.

Comment: a prime example of why outsourcing to cheap developers is a bad idea

Comment: Very dirty code. And not answered to start question.