# Magento1.9: Intercepting Order Post on Server Side

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to validate shipping addresses before an order goes through, but I cannot rely on a front end javascript approach.

I'm trying to find the code I'll need to customize that will allow me to run a regexp on the shipping address before approving an order.

If the regex matches, I'll need to return an error to the shopping cart page saying: "I'm sorry we cannot ship to that address".

Any ideas where I can find the code to do this?

I must approach it this way because I cannot ship to certain states, sometimes even only certain cities within certain states, so Magento's built-in regions doesn't cut it.

I already have this custom functionality to only shipping to certain states.

The problem is I need to only restrict these locations in the shipping address area, but not the billing.

I have already allowed billing to be any address while restricting the shipping, on the front end.  But there are ways to still get the restricted address into the shipping field such as "use billing address" for shipping, etc...

So as foolproof way to make sure no orders get through that have very specific shipping destinations, I want to validate the address on the server side and stop the order from going through if it matches my regular expression.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sales_order_place_before
```

You can use this observer to perform your checks before order save.

Check this to see how it works. [Event before save order or place order in magento 1.9.1.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/event-before-save-order-or-place-order-in-magento-1-9-1-1)

My suggestion is to do these validations before place order action. You can override both save billing/shipping actions.