# How can create observer in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create observer in magento1.9. I have a optional attribute for customer in option block cod and block list customer for place order.if get in option block cod then customer could not order cod and option block list then customer couldn't any order. I'm new in Magento

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this post

Link for observer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70534/77554

Link for validation: https://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Might this help you.